# rcarousel How to merge jquery statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to rcarousel and Jquery. I am trying to merge the following two statements together to get both the carousel working, and the images sized. I can't seem to merge these two statements together successfully to achieve the desired effect. Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks so much.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $( "#carousel" ).rcarousel( {width: 200, height: 200} );
});
```

```
jQuery(function($) {
$( "#carousel" ).rcarousel({
    auto: {enabled: true}
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

To merge them, just do this:

```
$("#carousel").rcarousel({auto: {enabled: true}, {width: 200, height: 200});
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hi Jack. Thanks for your help. I tried it and it did not seem to work. I am not sure if I need to add spaces, curly brackets or parens to get this working or not. Here is the code I used:    <script type="text/javascript"> 
         
         jQuery(function($) {
 
 $("#carousel" ).rcarousel({auto: {enabled: true}, {width: 200, height: 200} ); Thanks very much for your help (sorry, I am a novice to this :)